# no sound, Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: sound

I checked the basic sound settings.  I had installed the latest version of chrome for Linux, despite being warned not to, and now my sound doesn't work.  Everything worked fine for several weeks, including sound for flashplayer, which is why I installed chrome.  I tried to uninstall chrome using the Ubuntu Software Center, thinking I would start over, but Chrome doesn't appear as installed software.  I disabled automute using alsamixer and rebooted.  I downloaded the latest drivers and rebooted, and still no sound.  How do I get back to Ubuntu 12.10, nothing extra to start over?

Comment: How did you install Chrome, and you were you warned not to install it?

Comment: I downloaded the latest chrome package for Ubuntu, double-clicked.  It was opened by Ubuntu Software center, which issued the warning,  and I clicked "install anyway".

Comment: I am just guessing that the latest chrome caused the problem.

Comment: That warning's nothing to do with Chrome. You'll see it every time you install a .deb file, like you did for Chrome. Can you please open a terminal and type `alsamixer` and press enter? This'll open an application in the terminal that will details your various audio settings. Can you please take a screenshot of that and add it to your question? Make sure the terminal is wide enough to display the whole thing.

Comment: file:///home/gaseeley/Pictures/alsamixer.png

Comment: That must not have worked. LOL  How do I add the image to the question?

Comment: Click on the `edit` button at the bottom of your question, then click on the `img` button and upload it.

Comment: I am not feeling very capable:(  Where is the img button?

Comment: No worries mate. This is it here http://i.imgur.com/Ip5qi.png

Comment: This question should be closed as too localized since it's abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the installation of Google Chrome. I also faced the same problem but recovered it.

Google chrome is not in the software package list of Ubuntu. It is downloaded from the untrusted source. Did you remember that during the installation of the file you got a warning? Simply uninstall Google Chrome by typing the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
```

If it fails, type `unstable` in the place of `stable` (`sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-unstable`).

It was actually due to the installation of the virtual package of `google-chrome-stable`, which causes the pulseaudio daemon's startup to fail.